# Is there a way to check which input="file" I have selected between two inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two file="input" fields, with a output field, one is :

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"><br />
<output id="Filelist" style="max-width: 630px;"></output>
```

and the other is :

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files2" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"><br />
<output id="Filelist2" style="max-width: 630px;"></output>
```

Now, I'm trying to execute a method in javascript, but the execution of the method relies on which input field I have selected.

```
document.getElementById('Filelist').insertBefore(ul, null);
document.getElementById('Filelist2').insertBefore(ul, null);
```

I have applied the above code, but it only executes

`document.getElementById('Filelist2').insertBefore(ul, null);`

However, when I remove the aforementioned line, it executes  `document.getElementById('Filelist').insertBefore(ul, null);`

Is there a way for me to find out which input is being used so I can assign it to a variable?

Comment: what is `ul` here

Comment: @brk `var ul = document.createElement('ul');`

Comment: Please create a fiddle with your code

Answer (score 1):

That is because a child cannot have multiple parent. You are try to insert same child. For each of the `insertBefore` you need to create a separate `ul`. in order to solve your problem you can use `document.querySlectorAll` and  iterate through it and during each iteration create a new `ul` and add insert it

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.output').forEach(function(item) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  item.insertBefore(ul, null);

})
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"><br />
<output id="Filelist" class='output' style="max-width: 630px;"></output>


<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files2" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"><br />
<output id="Filelist2" class='output' style="max-width: 630px;"></output>
```

Comment: that works, but I need to insert the content into `output` after selecting that specific input field, right now it inserts it into both output fields, for example if I select id=files, the content should only appear in output id=Filelist, right now it appears in output id=Filelist2 as well